# Creating safe iframes in cross domain

Tags: javascript, html, url, cross-browser

I have to create an iframe in a page at `www.siteone.com`. The iframe src will be like `www.parentsite.com/formone.html`. I hope X-Frame options can be used to limit other websites from using parentsite form in `www.parentsite.com`.

Now my problem is that I have to generate forms in `parentsite.com` for some other user websites. In such cases, I cannot directly provide them the direct URL `www.parentsite.com/formxxx.html`. So I have to go for URL shortener/some other safe methods to restrict my form usage from other websites. In what way can I safely create URLs. One method is creating hash codes (say, public key/private keys) along with URL to prevent other site attacks.

But is this the only safe method available?? What other methods we can implement to prevent attacks like clickjacking in my case??

Note: User websites will be given javascript function for creating iframes in their websites

Comment: So even if you have a safe url lets say `/s4mp1eur1` would you not reference it in html while including iframe, and hence make it available in source code?

edit: i see mention of javascript function now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a dictionary of valid domains. When a petition comes to your form you check that the referrer of the petition is on your white list. If it's you serve the response, if it isn't you serve a message warning that the petition made is not allowed.